# first rails application - rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I have

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I thought I should get

```
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But how come I get

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because you're in development mode. In development mode `config.assets.debug` is `true` by default, preventing Sprockets from concatenating your javascript/css includes. In `config/evironments/development.rb` set

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Read about it in [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off).